# matplotlib.pyplot Event Handling: Linear Increase in Key-Press Dwell Time?

Tags: numpy, matplotlib, event-handling

I am writing an image processing module in Python using matplotlib.pyplot and numpy backend.
The images will largely be in tiff format, so the code below uses tifffile to convert a 3D image file to a 4D array in numpy. The below code aims to move through the z-plane of the 3D image, one image at a time, using z and x as hotkeys. My problem is quite interesting and I can't figure it out: the time between event and action (pressing x and displaying z+1 image) gets twice as long with each event. 
I timed it, results below:
1st z-press: 0.124 s
2nd z-prss: 0.250 s
3rd z-press: 0.4875 s

It is a bonafide linear increase, but I can't find where in my code the bug could be.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import tifffile as tiff

class Image:
    def __init__ (self, fname):
        self.fname = fname
        self.fig = plt.figure()
        self.z = 0
        self.ax = self.fig.add_subplot(111)
        self.npimg = tiff.imread(self.fname)
        self.plotimg()
        self.connect()

    def plotimg(self):
        plt.imshow(self.npimg[self.z][0])
        plt.show()

    def connect(self):
        self.cidkeypress = self.fig.canvas.mpl_connect('key_press_event',self.keypress)

    def disconnect(self):
        self.fig.canvas.mpl_disconnect(self.cidkeypress)

    def keypress(self, event):
        if event.key == 'x':
            self.z += 1
            self.plotimg()
        elif event.key == 'z':
            self.z -= 1
        self.plotimg()
```

Comment: Could you provide one of your tiff files for testing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you didn't provide an example file, I can't test your code. But I think the problem is, that you call `plt.imshow()` repeatedly. Each time a new `AxesImage` object is added to the Figure. This is why the timings increase linearly.

So the solution is to only have one `AxesImage` object and only update the data. Adapt `__init__` and `plotimg` as follows:

```
def __init__ (self, fname):
    self.fname = fname
    self.fig = plt.figure()
    self.z = 0
    self.ax = self.fig.add_subplot(111)
    self.npimg = tiff.imread(self.fname)
    self.pltim = plt.imshow(self.npimg[self.z][0])
    self.connect()
    plt.show()

def plotimg(self):
    self.pltim.set_data(self.npimg[self.z][0])
    plt.draw()
```

Beware: Untested code!

### EDIT:

#### Difference between `plt.imshow` and `plt.show`:

Despite their similar name, they do very different things: `plt.imshow` is a plotting function, which draws an image to the current axes (similar to `plt.plot`, `plt.scatter`, etc.) `plt.show` however, dispays the figure on the screen and enters the backends mainloop (i.e. blocks your code). [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3497578/matplotlib-plot-and-imshow) explains it in more detail

Comment: That did the trick. Question: plt.imshow creates an AxesImage object? What is the difference between plt.show and plt.imshow?