# Skeletonizing an image in Python

Tags: python, image-processing

```
import scipy.ndimage.morphology as m
import numpy as np
import cv2

def skeletonize(img):
h1 = np.array([[0, 0, 0],[0, 1, 0],[1, 1, 1]]) 
m1 = np.array([[1, 1, 1],[0, 0, 0],[0, 0, 0]]) 
h2 = np.array([[0, 0, 0],[1, 1, 0],[0, 1, 0]]) 
m2 = np.array([[0, 1, 1],[0, 0, 1],[0, 0, 0]])    
hit_list = [] 
miss_list = []
for k in range(4): 
    hit_list.append(np.rot90(h1, k))
    hit_list.append(np.rot90(h2, k))
    miss_list.append(np.rot90(m1, k))
    miss_list.append(np.rot90(m2, k))    
img = img.copy()
while True:
    last = img
    for hit, miss in zip(hit_list, miss_list): 
        hm = m.binary_hit_or_miss(img, hit, miss) 
        img = np.logical_and(img, np.logical_not(hm)) 
    if np.all(img == last):  
        break
return img

img = cv2.imread("e_5.jpg",0)
ret,img = cv2.threshold(img,127,255,0)
element = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_CROSS,(3,3))
img = 255 - img
img = cv2.dilate(img, element, iterations=3)

skel = skeletonize(img)
imshow(skel, cmap="gray", interpolation="nearest")
```

I have been trying this code inorder to skeletonize an image without any gaps in between the skeleton lines. But whenever I run the program , an error is hitting"imshow in not defined".

I tried plt.imshow, at this point, there was neither an error nor an output image. Can anyone tell me where am going wrong.

Comment: Would you mind to fix the indentation in the code you posted, please?

Comment: Would you mind posting a link to the image you're processing, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have forgotten to import the module using as short alias `plt` (note that the name can be replaced by what you wants), **AND** call the `show()` command so add the following to your code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.imshow()
plt.show()
```

see for more information: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3497922/4716013

Comment: no i did. its just i didnt add here. still nothing is displayed