# How to change matlibplot background color (when using imshow)

Tags: matplotlib

I want to change the background color of a plot created with imshow. However, the way to change the background only works based on the figure object

([Matplotlib figure facecolor (background color)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4804005/matplotlib-figure-facecolor-background-color))

...i.e., you need to use the figure object name: e.g.,

> rect.set_facecolor('red')

I have read that imshow creates a figure automatically.

([matplotlib plot and imshow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3497578/matplotlib-plot-and-imshow))

**Therefore, how can I tell what the automatically-created figure's name is, so that I can use set_facecolor( )**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `pyplot` you *can* create the figure by calling any plotting function. I.e.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.imshow(data)
plt.show()
```

creates a figure and shows it.

In this case you may change the figure background color via

```
plt.gcf().set_facecolor("red")
```

However it is often useful to create the figure explicitely:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.imshow(data)
fig.set_facecolor("red")
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @ImportanceOfBeingErnest

Comment: @CodeGuyJr Can you mark his answer as the correct answer? Because then other people can mark similar questions as duplicates of this one

Comment: @zwep Note that all that's needed for close-voting a question as duplicate is that the dupe-target has an answer and that answer is either upvoted **or** accepted. Hence if you want to close-vote a question, you may just upvote one of the target's answers to be able to do so.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Upvoted it. Thanks for the instruction; I am a noob here.

Comment: @Bazingaa Well, not out of disregard, but simply because it wasn't apparent to me that "mark correct" = click that little check mark. I just "upvoted" something and Stackoverflow prompted me to click the green arrow. Now I know.

Comment: @CodeGuyJr: No issues. I thought you already knew. But now you know :) Happy Stack Overflowing ;)

Comment: @Bazingaa Thanks :)

Comment: @Bazingaa Will do.